# Generator of group does not give 1 when raised to power of size of group

Tags: group-theory

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)), the order of an element of a group is as follows.

> The order of an element $a$ of a group, sometimes also called the period length or period of $a$, is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of the group, and $a^m$ denotes the product of $m$ copies of $a$.

I've been asked to show that $34$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{659}$

We know that an element is a generator of a group when its' order is equal to the order of said group.

So, given that $34$ is supposedly a generator, its' order will be $659$ (size of $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{659}$), where $34^{659} \pmod{659} = 1$, however, when I do $34^{659} \pmod{659}$ using modular exponentiation, I get $34$ and **not** $1$.

So how is $34$ a generator of $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{659}$ ??

**EDIT**

$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{659}$ is the multiplicative group of integers modulo $659$.

Comment: Formatting note:  try `\bmod` or `\pmod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of $\mathbb Z_{659}^*$ is $658$.  $0$ is not an element of the multiplicative group; it does not have an inverse.

$34^{658}\equiv1\bmod 659$.

Comment: That’s why $34^{659}\equiv34$

Comment: Thanks, I am an idiot.